# docker compose watch, use different file than docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker-compose

Has anyone tried `docker compose watch`? I'm testing it but I need to launch a compose file that has a different name than `docker-compose.yml`, I tried with:

```bash
docker compose watch -f compose-custom.yml
```

but I get this error:

> unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `docker compose --help`:

> Usage:  docker compose [OPTIONS] COMMAND

So you have to run:

```bash
docker compose -f compose-custom.yml watch
```